# Having problems with a login form in VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Ok so this is part of the program i am working on in vb.net what it should do is go into my MYSQL database and check to see what the user entered match's with the username/password in the database(simple login) but it is not working, it is stopping at the first if statement, i dont know why, but it goes down to the catch every time. i put in messagesbox's every other line to fine the problem so i know something is wrong with the if statements

```
    Dim rdr As MySqlDataReader = Nothing
    Myconnection = "Server=LocalHost; database=vb; user=root; password=tro63jans; "
    db_con.ConnectionString = Myconnection
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM login", db_con)


    Try
        db_con.Open()
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        Dim found As Boolean = False

        While rdr.Read()

            If username.ToUpper() = DirectCast(rdr("username"), String) Then

                If password = DirectCast(rdr("password"), String) Then

                    found = True
                    MessageBox.Show("you are log in")
                    Exit While

                Else

                    MessageBox.Show("username and password do not match", "Error")
                    txtpassword.Focus()

                End If

                If found Then

                    MessageBox.Show("user name not found", "error")
                    txtusername.Focus()
                    txtpassword.Focus()
                    Exit While

                End If

            Else

                If found Then
                    MessageBox.Show("User name not found", "error")
                    txtusername.Focus()

                End If
            End If
        End While
```

Comment: Please paste the exception you catch

Comment: i get no exception that is the thing, the only way i new where the problem was because i went everyother line and put a messagebox.show(1) then 2 and so on, it get stop at the if statments. but i dont know why.

Comment: If it goes to catch, there is an exception. You can see it for example by putting MsgBox(ex.Message) and MsgBox(ex.StackTrace) in your catch block. Also it seems that you need to learn debugging.

Comment: ^^^ That. And also why are you fetching all users?